# Print on file in a specific directory c#

Tags: file, printing, directory

I want to print my file .xps in a specific directory.
How can i do it?
this is my code:

```
printDocumentSempre.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer";
                    printDocumentSempre.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();

                    printDocumentSempre.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
                    printDocumentSempre.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".xps";
                    PaperSize papersize = new PaperSize("Dimensione fattura", 310, 800);
                    printDocumentSempre.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = papersize;

                    printDocumentSempre.Print();
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting the file name.  You're setting one here:

```
printDocumentSempre.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".xps";
```

It sounds like you also want to specify the full directory path in that file name.  The most immediate approach would be something like this:

```
printDocumentSempre.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = @"C:\path\to\file\" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".xps";
```

This is kind of sloppy, though.  Take a look at [the `Path` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) for building something a little more robust.  Perhaps like this:

```
printDocumentSempre.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = Path.Combine({@"C:\path", "to", "file", DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".xps"}).GetFullPath();
```

There's probably an even cleaner way that escapes me at the moment.  You'll find lots of functionality for interfacing with file systems in the `System.IO` namespace.  The `Path` object is particularly useful for manipulating fully qualified path/file names.